# Proof: The scalar of the inverse matrix is the matrix transpose.

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

if I have a Scalar Matrix A then in inverse is it the same as Matrix A transpose $(kA)^{-1} = A^T $ How can I prove this property? I would appreciate it if somebody can help me.

Comment: Isn't $A=\lambda I$ and  $A^T=A$, or do I misunderstand what a scalar matrix is?

Comment: Do you mean for $A \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(k A)^{-1} = A^T$ ($k A \neq 0$)?

Comment: yes @SampleTime

Answer (score 0):

For scalar $A, k$ you have $A^T = A$ and $(k A)^{-1} = 1/(k A)$ so just solve $A = 1/(k A)$ for $k$ you get $k = 1/A$. Of course this is only valid for $k A \neq 0$.